# How to convert Integer ArrayList in Java to int array in single line

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to convert the following ArrayList of Integer type to array of type int in java

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);  
arrlist.add(10);  
arrlist.add(20);  
arrlist.add(30);  
arrlist.add(40);
```

Output:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Comment: `int[] array = arrList.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();`

Comment: Consider utilizing _Integer_ arrays when converting to and from _Collection_ objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] intArray = arrlist.stream()
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .toArray();
```